Pine script for loop with `step_num`
Anyone who knows why this for loop is incrementing with -1 even though I explicitly tell it to increment with +1?
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

// © mickes

//@version=5
indicator("Test for loop", overlay = true)

ii = ""
for i = 10 to 0 by +1
    ii += str.format(" {0}", i)
runtime.error(str.format("{0}", ii))
plot(close)


Yes, because your for loop starts from 10 and goes till 0, irrespective of explicitly giving it +1. You should change the condition in the loop as below:
for i = 0 to 10 by 1


Okay, I've tried it and it does not change the behaviour unfortunately
